# HSQLDB query to replace a null value with a value derived from another record

Tags: sql, null, hsqldb, coalesce

This is a small excerpt from a much larger table, call it LOG:

```
RN EID FID FRID TID TFAID  
1 364   509 7045    null    7452  
2 364   509 7045    7452    null  
3 364   509 7045    7457    null  
4 375   512 4525    5442    5241  
5 375   513 4525    5863    5241  
6 375   515 4525    2542    5241  
7 576   621 5632    null    5452  
8 576   621 5632    2595    null  
9 672   622 5632    null    5966  
10 672  622 5632    2635    null
```

I would like a query that will replace the null in the 'TFAID' column with the value from the 'TFAID' column from the 'FID' column that matches.

Desired output would therefore be:

```
RN EID FID FRID TID TFAID  
1 364   509 7045    null    7452  
2 364   509 7045    7452    7452  
3 364   509 7045    7457    7452  
4 375   512 4525    5442    5241  
5 375   513 4525    5863    5241  
6 375   515 4525    2542    5241  
7 576   621 5632    null    5452  
8 576   621 5632    2595    5452  
9 672   622 5632    null    5966  
10 672  622 5632    2635    5966
```

I know that something like

```
    SELECT RN, 
        EID, 
        FID, 
        FRID, 
        TID, 
        (COALESCE TFAID, {insert clever code here}) AS TFAID
    FROM LOG
```

is what I need, but I can't for the life of me come up with the clever bit of SQL that will fill in the proper TFAID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HSQLDB supports SQL features that can be used as alternatives. These features are not supported by some other databases.

```
CREATE TABLE LOG (RN INT, EID INT, FID INT, FRID INT, TID INT, TFAID INT);

-- using LATERAL
SELECT l.RN, l.EID, l.FID, l.FRID, l.TID, 
   COALESCE(l.TFAID, f.TFAID) AS TFAID
   FROM LOG l , LATERAL (SELECT MAX(TFAID) AS TFAID FROM LOG f WHERE f.FID = l.FID) f

-- using scalar subquery
SELECT l.RN, l.EID, l.FID, l.FRID, l.TID, 
   COALESCE(l.TFAID, (SELECT MAX(TFAID) AS TFAID FROM LOG f WHERE f.FID = l.FID)) AS TFAID
   FROM LOG l
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it looks like it may simplify my life, but I'm not sure how to implement it in my query structure.  The question above is just a small piece in a much larger query with multiple joins.  I'm new to SQL and very new to HSQLDB, and the user guide at http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/sqlgeneral-chapt.html doesn't seem to have much on the use of lateral.  Using the example above, could you explain how the query works?  Thanks for your time.

Comment: Use the scalar subquery if LATERAL is too difficult to implement. In both cases for each value that is null, a subquery is executed to fetch the not-null value from other rows.

Comment: The scalar approach you gave also gets to my answer, but with significantly less complexity than the first answer given.  This approach also improves processing time of the query by almost 50% (~5 secs to ~2.5 secs).  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach.  This aggregates the log to get the value and then joins the result in:

```
SELECT l.RN, l.EID, l.FID, l.FRID, l.TID, 
       COALESCE(l.TFAID, f.TFAID) AS TFAID
FROM LOG l join
     (select fid, max(tfaid) as tfaid
      from log
      group by fid
     ) f
     on l.fid = f.fid;
```

There may be other approaches that are more efficient.  However, HSQL doesn't implement all SQL features.

Comment: That fit the bill.  I forgot to mention that everything except the 'RN' column might repeat a number of times, but all the repeats are keyed to another column 'R' that I didn't include.  By modifying your answer to group by fid and r and join on fid and r, this got me right to the answer I needed.  Thanks for the fast and accurate response!

Comment: @Gordon Linoff, Which SQL features HSQLDB does not implement? See the alternative answers below which could be more efficient for larger data sets.